# Is this circuit suitable for switching 3 kA?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, high-current

So I wish to switch a current of roughly 3 kA on for short periods of time roughly every second. I have created a circuit shown below which I believe will be sufficient but after past failures I would really like to check with people who might know what they are doing. The first image shows the current through the loosely named "load" R11, but is the load nontheless, while the second image shows the heat generation in watts in the MOSFET. This appears to be at about 90 W normally but under switching hits 1.4 kW which seems very high. This event only occurs for 160 ns (288 nC/1.8 A) but is that enough to make it go boom? If that is going to be fine then the rest of the circuit should live I would think. It will be mounted onto an aluminium water cooling block so should stay cool, I am just mainly concerned about those massive spikes during switching. Should I be switching them even faster? Currently 1.8 A going into the gates but I am not sure how to increase that. If it is fine then yay if not any input about improving the performance of this circuit would be good, before I go and blow up 6 more MOSFETs.

Some extra detail: V1 controls the driver, V2 is the high current power supply for the circuit and yes is a battery designed to do that.

P.s. Here's the data sheet of the mosfets I am using: https://www.vishay.com/docs/79764/sqjq140e.pdf and if anyone wants to tell me "even though they say they can handle 700 amps they actually can't it's a lie", here's a similarly if not worse spec'd mosfet doing exactly what I am looking for, seemingly without a heatsink: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrktIIbV8Qc&ab_channel=Nexperia so I know it is possible. Data sheet for that if you're interested: https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/BUK7S0R5_40H-2392070.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: The MOSFET in your diagram does not appear to be one that you have linked.

Comment: My software does not have the same mosfet but the one I chose has the same RDS on and similar gate capacitance :)

Comment: Node names on graphs are meaningless to anyone reading this question. Name nodes by labelling please.

Comment: I have added labels now :)

Comment: The MOSFETs will never turn on at the same time because of the practical imperfections and device-to-device imbalances. So, one MOSFET will take significant amount of current compared to others *(maybe the total current as a worst case)* for a short amount of time. You need to take this into account (Check SOA and Rth graphs). Ideally, you need to select a MOSFET that is able to switch the total current, and then you can think about paralleling.

Comment: rather than a single M1/M2, I'd be inclinded to duplicate those, one pair per big MOSFET, each with their own very local reservoir cap

Comment: Split R11 into 6 higher values that feed each MOSFET individually (this keeps current sharing more or less in line.

Comment: One other thing to consider is the spikes: Since you are switching very high amount of current, any small inductance (can be in order of fractional nanohenries or even tens of nanohenries) coming from the connections will create a good amount of spike across the MOSFETs when they go off. If the spikes are high enough then they can be destructive for the MOSFETs even though they are rated for 3.5 times the supply voltage. Spikes also depend on dV/dt i.e. slowing the switching down (increase rise/fall times) reduces the spikes but also increases losses. Put a 3nH inductor in series and simulate.

Comment: Please specify the rise and fall times, and min/max pulse width, rep rate, etc. And load range -- resistance and voltage. And load inductance is critical here. The above comments about gate drive speed are probably irrelevant, or even irresponsible, given the waveforms shown here, but rise time must be chosen judiciously in any case, and we lack information required to provide that assistance. Finally, if you're blowing up transistors, I guess you've actually built this? Please show layout as well.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Do you mean find a mosfet that is able to handle the full 3kA, does that exist? Or do you mean something else? Also is there any way to avoid one taking all the current? I was hoping to try and avoid this by using a large input current or perhaps a capacitor reservoir like another comment suggested.

Comment: @TimWilliams Rise and fall times, like the 160ns rise and fall times I mentioned in the post? Pulse width, like duty cycle? Doesn't matter too much just around 1hz and adjustable duty cycle but I will take care of that later. For now it's a small duty cycle. I don't fully understand your comment it seems like you are asking for a lot of stuff I already put in the original question. And also like I said this is a new circuit the original one was very poor and not relevant. I am simply asking for advice from people who have dealt with parallel mosfets in the past and high currents.

Comment: OK, let me be more specific. What values of V2 will the application see? Precisely 12.000V? Any others? What values of R11, 4.200mΩ precisely, or any others? What range for each. What inductance does the resistor have? What is the resistor doing, surely it is not dumping power for the sake of dumping power, is it? "Adjustable duty cycle" -- over what range? It matters a great deal if you want 10% or say 0.01% minimum.

Comment: @leasthollow yes, but that's to deal with the worst case. `does that exist?` I don't know but I know some able to switch 2 kA are available. Have a look at onsemi and Toshiba MOSFETs. I'm sure there are a few, but they must be ridiculously expensive. `Also is there any way to avoid one taking all the current?` welcome to the dark world of paralleling! For a few tens of amps this usually can be ignored but for your case it can't. Layout is very important. One way is to place high enough cap across G-S to "neglect" Ciss variation but will slow down the switching therefore increase the losses.

Answer (score 2):

No issue with the per device continuous current limits.  These devices are tough and can deliver the performance you quote.

However, as noted by others, you have quite a number of issues to deal with if this application (paralleling) is going to work reliably.

- Total gate drive current requirements
- Maximum peak current during switching due to threshold differences
- Inductance in gate drive (limiting rise time, and causing gate spikes)
- Inductance in power circuit (leading to switching spikes at turn off, with need for snubbers)

The devices you reference have a pulse current limit of 1820A for < 300us pulse and 2% duty cycle.  This is high, but if one takes all the current during switch on will likely be exceeded...

There are a fair number of app notes on paralleling FETs, including [this one from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa020/slpa020.pd), which highlights particular challenges related to layout and inductance, and [this one from Infineon](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Parallel_Operation_of_Power_MOSFET_.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b426db703ad9&fileId=db3a30431ed1d7b2011eee77009e547a&ack=t) with a particular focus on dynamic current imbalance.

I would suggest you look carefully at the reference designs, in particular some of the protection components for the effect of inductance, and the layout constraints.

I would strongly suggest you start with a single FET design for switching a lower scaled current pulse, and carefully observe actual switching waveforms on gates and load.

Once you have worked out the issues with that design, produce a multi-device setup, and work up to the full design in steps (1 FET, 2 FET, 4 FET, 6 FETs with scaled loads).

This will allow you to debug bits of the problem at a time, rather than trying to do all at once (which is almost certainly going to let out a lot of "magic smoke").

**Edit:** [This](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-PowerMOSFET_Paralleling_power_MOSFET_in_high_current_applications-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462758f5bd101759ca434f111c1&da=t) article from Infineon goes into much more detail on the pitfalls of paralleling FETs, in particular the troubles with current sharing due to device variation.  It includes some excellent graphs/traces showing the extend of problems you can expect.

Comment: So looks like theres a couple ways I could do this. If I increase the load resistance to 0.00667 then max current at any one time becomes (12/0.00667=1800) roughly 1800 amps right. That gives me a <300us window to turn on all MOSFETs, which I think is achievable. Otherwise if I can experiment with scaled loads, probably cut lengths of wire for such low resistances, and see if I can get pairs working with 3 driver circuits. If such a thing is possible then my max current over <300us becomes 3600 which I can easily work with, if that's how all that works.

Comment: Other than that I need to read up on inductance within high speed switching circuits and see what protection I can add. I never thought I would need protection from 1 loop of wire but I guess the sheer amount of current here is the problem right? Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: That all makes sense. Be aware that the 1820A is from the "Absolute Maximum" section of the datasheet, so view it as a hard limit not a guide, and some headroom would help reliability.. Do update with experiences once you have a working solution.

Comment: alright it's been a while but it works, had it switching 1500 amps reliably, it does get a bit hot though.